# How to show a different digits for each variable with the table1 package for R?

Tags: r, function

I have produced a table with the [table1 package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/table1.pdf) and followed instructions in this [example 1 rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/table1/versions/1.1/vignettes/table1-examples.Rmd).

I cannot work out how to add different digits to statistics (such as years, which could have only 2 digits) and the qrs numerical valuable, which should have 4 digits in this example.

I'm using this code:

```
labels <- list(
  variables=list(sex="Sex",
                 age="Age (years)",
                 qrs_pre="QRS (ms)")
)

strata <- c(list(Total=df), split(df, df$sex))

my.render.cont <- function(x) {
  with(stats.apply.rounding(stats.default(x), digits=3, c("",
                                                           "Mean (SD)"=sprintf("%s (&plusmn; %s)", MEAN, SD))))
}

my.render.cat <- function(x) {
  c("", sapply(stats.default(x), function(y) with(y,
                                                  sprintf("%d (%0.0f %%)", FREQ, PCT))))
}

table1(strata, labels,
       render.continuous=my.render.cont, 
       render.categorical=my.render.cat)
```

With this result:
[table1 output (imgur, it's in portuguese but it's the same idea)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmUBJ.png)

I have tried changing the digits=3 to digits=c("3", "4"), creating different my.render.cont functions (but couldn't apply them to render.continuous later), and also using if and ifelse statements in my.render.cont functions, all to no avail.

Does anyone kindly have any suggestion on how I could work it out? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```r
my.render <- function(x, name, ...) {
  if (name == "age") {
    render.default(x=x, name=name, ..., digits=2)
  } else if (name == "qrs_pre") {
    render.default(x=x, name=name, ..., digits=4)
  } else {
    render.default(x=x, name=name, ...)
  }
}


table1(strata, labels, render=my.render)
```